# Are 'peak frame rate' and 'variable frame rate' the same thing?

Tags: video, encoding, frame

I can find the term 'peak frame rate' in some video editing software.

Are 'peak frame rate' and 'variable frame rate' the same thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 'constant frame rate' and 'variable frame rate' both having obvious meanings:
https://www.bandicam.com/support/tips/vfr-cfr/

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_frame_rate

https://handbrake.fr/docs/en/latest/technical/frame-rates.html

When you use VFR then you can select which are the minim, averaged and **maximum** frame rates. And that maximum is the same as "*peak*" frame rate.

Comment: Thank you now I understood. In case he select VFR option, he should clarify its maximum frame rate. I guess minimum or average frame rate are less significant.